# Issues during installation of python jnius library. (dependencies?)

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, pyjnius

I would like to install jnius library for python using pip. I'm getting an error during installation. Here is what happend:

```
C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python.exe -m pip 
install jnius
Collecting jnius
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/f5/5673f3906a9e8ca68cb7bc2d9a1eaa944c321271c4af621dbb51c13d385a/jnius-1.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.0 in 
c:\users\janka\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages 
(from jnius) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in 
c:\users\janka\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages 
(from jnius) (0.28.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: jnius
```

The first error I can't solve:
possibly, I do not have setup.py file. Can I install it somehow through pip? or what should I do? maybee I do have It, if so, where can I find it or how do I check it?

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jnius ... error
Complete output from command 
C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c 
"import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Janka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
pnoxk945\\jnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
wheel-ngvrr7r6 --python-tag cp35:
WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
```

(Well, windows did not give up :D)

```
       Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
copying jnius_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\reflect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
running build_ext
cythoning jnius\jnius.pyx to jnius\jnius.c
building 'jnius' extension
```

Well, I need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, I tried the suggested link, but the web page says "expired account"

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual 
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for jnius
Running setup.py clean for jnius
Failed to build jnius
Installing collected packages: jnius
```

and again, the setup.py file..

```
Running setup.py install for jnius ... error
Complete output from command 
C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c 
"import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Janka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
pnoxk945\\jnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-rdnylq3b\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile:
WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
         Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
copying jnius_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\reflect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
copying jnius\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\jnius
running build_ext
skipping 'jnius\jnius.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'jnius' extension
```

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required  - again, where can I get it? / how do I install it?

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual 
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe 
-u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Janka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
pnoxk945\\jnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-rdnylq3b\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
install-pnoxk945\jnius\

C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>
```

(I am using windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio 2015. During install tick the box for `Languages--> C++.`
Also you may need to set your environment variable

```
GYP_MSVS_VERSION = 2015
```

Alternatively you could download the C++ compiler for Python 2.7 here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

More details on the installation can be found here 
https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-for-windows

Comment: And what if I installed Visual Studio 2017? Isn't it compatible too?

And what about setup.py  bdist_wheel for jnius - run error? If I do have the file, where should I look for it? If I don't (I think I don't), how can I get it?

Comment: It should work fine. You will have to try it out by yourself. Alternatively you could use the c++ compiler from the below link. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 . As per the documentation for Jnius this should work fine.

Comment: okay, and how can I set the enviroment variable for non admin user in windows? I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730964(v=technet.10) , but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Well, I it worked without setting the variables too :). thanks for advice.